# Rails find record where attribute is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do a record search with a `where` method in which there are two conditions, one of which must be nil.

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.0.0, and Postgres.

I have an app with three models: User, Drm, and DrmMorning.  Users have many Drms, and Drms have many DrmMornings.  I am trying to isolate a single DrmMorning record so that I can edit it.

This is the update action in my drm_mornings controller:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @drm = Drm.where(user_id: @user.id).last
  @drm_mornings = DrmMorning.where(" drm_id = ? AND location = ?", @drm.id, nil).first || DrmMorning.where(" drm_id = ? AND happy = ?", @drm.id, nil).first 
  if @drm_mornings.nil? 
    flash[:error] = "thanks for finishing up"
    render 'drm/intro'
  elsif @drm_mornings.update_attributes(morning_params)
    redirect_to 'ep_feelings'
  else
    flash[:error] = "something is broken"
    render 'drm/intro'
  end
end
```

How do I perform a database search for the most recent single record  that satisfies two conditions, one of which is the null-value for one of the attributes?

The intent is to grab the first incomplete DrmMorning record for the most recent Drm of the current user.    These records are edited in two stages after creation, hence the - if this is `nil`, if that is `nil` structure of the assignment.

Whenever I call the method it acts like `@drm_morning` is empty, sending to `drm/intro` with a flash saying thanks for finishing up.

That record shouldn't be empty, though.  In the console when I call `DrmMorning.last` I get this output:

```
DrmMorning id: 8, name: "breakfast", begain: "7:00", end: "7:30", drm_id: 3, user_id: 1, created_at: "2013-10-12 20:04:29", updated_at: "2013-10-12 20:04:29", commuting: nil, shopping: nil, housework: nil, other_action_words: nil, other_action: nil, location: nil, interaction: nil, spouse: nil, friend: nil, co_worker: nil, parent: nil, child: nil, client: nil, boss: nil, student: nil, other_person: nil, other_person_words: nil, happy: nil, depressed: nil, angery: nil, enjoy: nil, pain: nil, fatigue: nil, active: nil, person_id: nil
```

As I read this  it should satisfy the condition in the update action. I checked and the `current_user` function is working, and I've been able to assign the `@drm` variable with just that code elsewhere.  Am I using where incorrectly?

---

The syntax for checking nil values is "ATTRIBUTE *IS* NULL" rather than "ATTRIBUTE = nil", which looks for the value 'nil' in the record.

Comment: if you've solved this, add an answer then check it so it's out of the unanswered queue.  welcome to s/o :)

Comment: Thanks--It wouldn't allow me to answer it until this AM as I don't have enough rep.  It won't let me select my own answer until tomorrow, but I'll select Edgar's for the time being to get it out of the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax within the `where` function for checking nil values is not

```
ATTRIBUTE = nil
```

but rather

```
ATTRIBUTE IS nil
```

Comment: Missed that, better use SomeModel.where(my_atribute: nil), it will properly construct the query.

Comment: Is that an option when you have two conditions you are looking to satisfy in your .where query?  I was under the impression that this wouldn't work.  Sorry for the poorly worded question--I will reword to make clearer that I am speaking of a .where call that specifies two conditions.

Comment: 'ATTRIBUTE IS nil' doesn't work for me. Use 'ATTRIBUTE IS NULL' instead.
If you use the expression directly with where(), you can also go with @EdgarsJekabsons approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a breakpoint and play in the console, something obviously is different from what You are searching in console.
Gem for debugging https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug

Also You have a strange table design - why You need a user column in DrmMorning if DrmMorning belongs to Drm and Drm belongs to user? You can access those from users using has_many through.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I hadn't looked at the has-many-through association, only the the has many/belongs to pair.  Thanks for the pointer, and the gem suggestions.